# How to configure DHCP server rules to assign different IP ranges for different racks

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

I want to configure DHCP server rules such that different racks are assigned different IP ranges. Every rack has around 20 servers and there are 10 racks, how do I configure DHCP server such that every rack gets a different IP range, every rack has a top of the rack switch. I am trying to build a native rack awareness tool where one can figure out which servers are sitting in which racks.

Comment: Is the DHCP server on the device into which each rack switch is connected, or is it running on a separate device?

Comment: What you describe is better served by a Domain Controller. I would probably handle everything at the OU level. My only experience is a fairly large VM cluster though and the VMs have static ip addresses. Individual VMs are handled by VMware View and VCenter configurations.

Comment: Are you hoping to keep all of the hosts on all of these racks on the same broadcast domain (e.g. same VLAN) and same IP subnet as all the rest? If so, it'll be difficult. IP is agnostic of the data-link layer, and Ethernet is agnostic of the network layer. There is no standard way to attach Ethernet topology information (like which switch/port a given device is connected to) to DHCP packets. So you might end up having to create a separate VLAN and subnet for each rack, if you really want the servers to get IP addresses based solely on which rack they're in.

Comment: I know IP is agnostic if we are using same domain. But how would I build a rack awareness tool for dell servers ? There is no way other way I can think of.